# how to access remote desktop file using java /Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a windows remote desktop, along with its IP & credentials and some config files in it & want to read those files using java or web application (Java EE).
Is this possible (if not java any other tech)? Any libraries for this? 
Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking for off site resources is off topic. Also, your question is very poor as it shows no effort.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis do u think i wouldnt have searched for it /tried it? really?

Comment: Show what you've found and what you've tried.

Comment: though its in my client system, i will put in words for you, i tried udp, tcp, jrdesktop library. but no luck with anything. Because its not a remote location but windows handles the remote desktop with rdp layer

Comment: & i dont see how this is a off topic, since its a honest programming question... or is there any stackoverflow specific for reference helps

Comment: i was just hoping someone who tried this might lend me a hand.

Comment: If you have an ftp server on the remote machine, you can access the file through that.

Comment: actually its just some config files and the number of lan desktop to access are a lot...so i was hoping to find a way from a single server to access them all - if possible